# What is a right $\mathsf{C}$-set?

Tags: category-theory

In the book *Categories, Allegories* Freyd and Scedrov present the following definition.
Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a small category. A **right** $\mathsf{C}$-**set** is a set $X$ together with

1. a unary operation from $X$ to the objects of $\mathsf{C}$
2. a partial binary operation from $X$ and the arrows of $\mathsf{C}$ to $X$

satisfying certain axioms.

Since I've never found this concept elsewhere but I know that the book is famous for its idiosyncrasies and cumbersome notations, I'm wondering whether there is a more familiar and less painful way to see it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Let's observe that a function $\varphi\colon X\to \mathrm{Ob}(C)$ is the same as a family of pairwise disjoint sets indexed by $\mathrm{Ob}(C)$, i.e., $(X_a)_{a\in \mathrm{Ob}(C)}$ with $X_a\cap X_b = \varnothing$  when $a\neq b$.

Indeed, given $\varphi\colon X\to \mathrm{Ob}(C)$, we can define $X_a = \{x\in X\mid \varphi(x) = a\}$. Conversely, given $(X_a)_{a\in \mathrm{Ob}(C)}$, we can define $X = \bigcup_{a\in \mathrm{Ob}(C)}X_a$ and define $\varphi\colon X\to \mathrm{Ob}(C)$ by $\varphi(x) = a$ when $x\in X_a$.

Now the definition of right $C$-set doesn't say we have a binary operation  $X\times \mathrm{Ar}(C)\to X$ but rather a *partial* binary operation  $\cdot \colon X\times \mathrm{Ar}(C)\to X$, with $x\cdot f$ defined if and only if $\varphi(x) = \mathrm{dom}(f)$. The axioms assert that $\varphi(x\cdot f) = \mathrm{cod}(f)$, and $x\cdot \mathrm{id}_a = x$, and $(x\cdot f)\cdot g = x\cdot (f\circ g)$ when these partial binary operations are defined.

Translating: For each object $a$ in $C$, we have a set $X_a$ such that the family $(X_a)_{a\in \mathrm{Ob}(C)}$ is pairwise disjoint sets. Further, for each arrow $f\colon a\to b$ in $C$, we have a function $(-)\cdot f\colon X_a\to X_b$. The function associated to each identity arrow is the identity function, and these functions compose in the obvious way.

I hope it's clear now that aside from the requirement that the sets $X_a$ be pairwise disjoint, a right $C$-set is the same thing as a functor from $C$ to the category of sets. The point of this odd-looking definition is that it presents the category of functors $C\to \mathsf{Set}$ as the models of an [essentially algebraic theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory).

Answer (score 3):

The notion of a $C$-set for a category $C$ is intended to generalize the action of a group on a set to the action of a category on a set.

Take $C$ to be the delooping of a group $G$, i.e., a groupoid with one object whose morphisms are the elements of $G$ and composition of morphisms is given by multiplication in $G$.

Now, a $C$-set $X$ consists of a function $X\to\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ and a function $X\times \mathrm{Mor}(C)\to X$ which together satisfy some axioms. In the case that $C = \mathbf{B}G$ the first map consists of no data since $\rm Ob(C) = \{*\}$, but the second map together with the properties it is intended to satisfy are precisely the data of a right group action $X\times G\to X$.

The moral meaning and origin of the properties that such a pair of maps are intended to satisfy in order to comprise a $C$-set are pretty obfuscated in Freyd and Scedrov. In fact, their definition itself is a bit opaque and can instead be derived, as you intuited, from something much less painful.

$\textbf{Definition}:$ Given a category $C$, a right $C$-set $X$ is a functor $X:C\to\rm Set$.

If we take $A = \bigsqcup_{c\in\mathrm{Ob}(C)}X(c)$, then the definition of Freyd and Scedrov and the subsequent axioms emerge more or less naturally. Firstly we require a map $u:A\to\mathrm{Ob}(C)$. This is the canonical map sending a pair $(x,c)$ to $c$. We further require a partially defined function $\rho: A\times\mathrm{Mor}(C)\to A$ that is defined for pairs $((x,c),f)$ iff $s(f) = c$, and this map should send a pair $((x,c),f)$ to $(x',t(f))$ where $x'\in X(t(f))$.

Here $s$ is the *source map* $s:\mathrm{Mor}(C)\to\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ which sends a morphism $f:c\to c'$ to its domain or "source" $c$ and $t:\mathrm{Mor}(C)\to \mathrm{Ob}(C)$ is the *target map* that sends a morphism $f:c\to c'$ to its domain or "target" $c'$. These conditions on $\rho$ account for the properties mentioned in Freyd and Scedrov that "the binary operation $xa$ is defined iff $x\square = \square a$", and that "$(xa)\square = (((xa)\square)(a\square)))$".

This can be all be summarized succinctly however by simply requiring that $\rho: A\times_{s}\mathrm{Mor}(C)\to A$ such that $u\circ \rho = t\circ \pi_{2}$. Here the domain of $\rho$ is defined by taking the pullback (fiber product) of $u$ along $s$, and $\pi_{2}:A\times_{s}\mathrm{Mor}(C)\to \mathrm{Mor}(C)$ is just the projection.

The map $\rho$ can be explicitly defined for a pair $(x,c)\in A$ and morphism $f:c\to c'$ as $\rho((x,c),f) = (X(f)(x),c')$. Notice that $\rho$ is entirely canonical and only requires the data prescribed by the functor $X$, furthermore the above properties are immediately satisfied by definition. The remaining axioms required by Freyd and Scedrov after making this definition amount to stating the consequences of the functoriality of $X$ on $\rho$. Thus the functor $X$ really does package the notion of a $C$-set in a painless and canonical way.

You can read about all of this in more detail [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+of+a+category+on+a+set)!